# Update values in multiple tables using SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables called `ProfileMain` and `UserDomainMain` I want to save the columns for the two tables in from one form using model.

While saving I get an error like this

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ProfileM__290C88E4EE2362CC'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProfileMain'. The duplicate
>   key value is (22). The statement has been terminated.

My procedure code:

```
create procedure ProfileInsert
    @ProfileId varchar(50),
    @First varchar(50),
    @Last varchar(50),
    @Gender varchar(50),
    @DOB varchar(50),
    @Country varchar(50),
    @Mobile varchar(50),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @State varchar(50),
    @City varchar(50),
    @UserDomainId varchar(50),
    @Tags varchar(50),
    @AreaofInterest varchar(50),
    @CurrentDomain varchar(50),
    @WorkingAt varchar(50)
as
begin
   insert into ProfileMain   
   values(@ProfileId, @First, @Last, @Gender, @DOB, @Country, @Mobile, @Email, @State, @City)

   insert into UserDomain 
   values(@UserDomainId, @ProfileId, @WorkingAt, @CurrentDomain, @AreaofInterest, @Tags)
end
```

and my save method:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProfileInsert", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileId",SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserDomainId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkingAt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentDomain", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaofInterest", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tags", SqlDbType.VarChar);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
return View("Index", promodel);
```

Comment: AddWithValue requires, as second parameter, the Value to be written to the database, not the type

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user should check the documentation before.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your procedure like this:

```
create procedure ProfileInsert
@ProfileId varchar(50),@First varchar(50),@Last varchar(50),@Gender varchar(50),@DOB varchar(50),@Country varchar(50),@Mobile varchar(50),@Email varchar(50),@State varchar(50),@City varchar(50),
@UserDomainId varchar(50),
@Tags varchar(50),@AreaofInterest varchar(50),@CurrentDomain varchar(50),@WorkingAt varchar(50)
as
begin
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from ProfileMain where ProfileId=@profileId)
BEGIN
   insert into ProfileMain values(@ProfileId,@First,@Last,@Gender,@DOB,@Country,@Mobile,@Email,@State,@City)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE ProfileMain SET First=@First,Last=@Last,Gender=@Gender,DOB=@DOB,Country=@Country,Mobile=@Mobile,Email=@Email,State=@State,City@City where ProfileId=@profileId;
END

insert into UserDomain values(@UserDomainId,@ProfileId,@WorkingAt,@CurrentDomain,@AreaofInterest,@Tags)
end
```

Comment: Please use `IF EXISTS(...)` instead of `COUNT(*) > 0` - on a large table, this can make a **huge** difference!

Comment: s i used the above procedure but the datas saved into second table but not in first table. it store 22 in all columns in first table